# Как правильно в php вызвать функцию внутри функции?

Tags: php

Как в php вызвать функцию внутри функции?

Есть такой код:

```
  function getAge($y, $m, $d) {
    if($m > date('m') || $m == date('m') && $d > date('d'))
      return (date('Y') - $y - 1);
    else
      return (date('Y') - $y);
  }
```

Внутри функции getAge() вызывается еще одна функцию (точнее несколько) date().
Как правильно делать так, чтобы не было ошибок?

Comment: а какие есть ошибки сейчас? Можете вызывать сколько угодно функций внутри других, лишь бы сами не потерялись потом при отладке всего этого.

Comment: Вот такая ошибка выводится: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getAge() (previously declared in ... )

Comment: Могу предположить,что "ещё одна функция" - это ты создал функцию и назвал её `date`? Функция `date()` - стандартная функция PHP, называть свои функции зарезервированными именами функций PHP нельзя.

Comment: нет, date() это стандартная функция. Если писать так:
`if($m > date('m') || $m == date('m') && $d > date('d'))
      return (date('Y') - $y - 1);
    else
      return (date('Y') - $y);`
то все нормально. А если все это сделать функцией, то ошибка (которую указал выше).

Comment: @Ilnyr На самом деле дословно ваша ошибка переводится "Нельзя переопределить функцию getAge()" Судя по этому у вас в скрипте есть две функции с именем getAge

Comment: Да, это знаю что 2 раза нельзя. Функция getAge в проекте только 1 раз, больше не создавал

Comment: Я тут заметил, каким-бы именем функцию не называл, везде ошибка `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ...`

Comment: @Ilnyr Покажите код вызова функции с параметрами, которые вы ей передаёте

Comment: Вот к примеру: 
`function qqqqqqqqqqqq() {
 echo '111';
}` та же ошибка

Comment: @Ilnyr ну проблема то явно не в функции, а там, где вы её выводите